# How to get orders all of which have a common status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an implementation of orders and order items. That is, each order has a certain number of items.

Each order item has a status field that is "controlled" by an enum.

```rb
enum status: {
  opened: 0,
  checked: 1,
  spoiled: 2
}, _prefix: :status
```

Can you please tell me how I can get only those orders within which all items have the "checked" status?

I'm stuck in this:

```rb
left_outer_joins(:orders_items)
  .where(
    orders_items: {
      status: :checked
    }
  )
  .where(orders_items: { id: nil })
  # OR .where.missing(:orders_items)
```

Or:

```rb
left_outer_joins(:orders_items)
  .where(
    orders_items: {
      status: %i[
        opened
        spoiled
      ]
    }
  )
  .having('COUNT(orders_items.id) = 0')
  .group('orders.id')
```

As far as I understand, I somehow need to get orders in which:

- There are no items with a status other than "checked";
- OR
- The number of items with the "checked" status is equal to the number of all items in the order;
- OR
- The number of items with any status other than "checked" is zero.

But I do not understand how this can be done... I hope for your help

Comment: Both of those conditions are logically the same. If `The number of items with the "checked" status is equal to the number of all items in the order.` then all the items must have the "checked" status.

Comment: @max I agree, but I still don't understand how to get this data. I indicate the status "checked", but `where(orders_items: { id: nil })` does not work for me - I get an empty array. And how to implement what I described in the second paragraph in SQL, I do not understand at all (I think this is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this. The simplest way is a WHERE NOT IN subquery:

```
Order.where.not(
  id: Order.joins(:order_items)
           .where.not(order_items: { status: :checked })
)
```

You can also use NOT EXIST:

```
Order.where(
  OrderItem.select(:id)
      .where(
          # order_items.version_id = orders.id
          OrderItem.arel_table[:order_id].eq(Order.arel_table[:id])
       )
       .where.not(status: :checked)
       .arel
       .exists.not
)
```

These both rely on the fact that a order with any order_item that does not have `status = 1` does not match the criteria. If you want something thats closer to the paragraph `The number of items with the "checked" status is equal to the number of all items in the order.` you can use subqueries:

```
orders, order_items =  Order.arel_table, OrderItem.arel_table
subquery = OrderItem.select(order_items[:*].count)
                     .where(order_items[:order_id].eq(order[:id]))
                
Order.select(
        orders[*],
        subquery.arel.as('order_items_count'), # can be replaced with a counter-cache
        subquery.where(status: :checked).arel.as('checked_count')
     )
     .where(orders[:order_items_count].eq(orders[:not_checked_count])
```

Or aggregation:

```
orders, order_items = Order.arel_table, OrderItem.arel_table
subquery = OrderItem.select(order_items[:*].count)
                     .where(order_items[:order_id].eq(order[:id]))
                
Order
    .left_joins(:order_items)
    .select(
        orders[*],
        subquery.where(status: :checked).arel.as('checked_count')
     )
     .group(:id)
     .having(
       order_items[:*].eq(orders[:checked_count]) 
     )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. You helped me a lot to solve the problem and understand the implementation logic.

Comment: I dunno if my logic is sound but to me all the three points actually sound like paraphrases of the same thing - like a trick question. Is this an actual commercial project, a interview question or academia?

Comment: Yes, three points say the same thing. At that moment, I tried to state all my thoughts on implementation. I try myself in the implementation of a small online store for friends. And suddenly there was such a problem :)